# how to customize Sylius in order to sell free products (by default the min. price is 0.01)

Tags: php, validation, doctrine-orm, symfony, sylius

I've got to make a shop based on sylius able to sell free products.
In order to do so, I've followed the doc "[Customizing Validation](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/validation.html)" and made thoses modifications :

```
#AppBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ChannelPricing:
    # see http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/validation.html
    #the original constraint said that the minimum price is 0.01 in vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/validation/ChannelPricing.xml
    properties:
        price:
            - NotBlank:
                message: sylius.channel_pricing.price.not_blank
                groups: [app_product]
            - Range:
                min: 0
                minMessage: app.channel_pricing.price.min
                groups: [app_product]
```

---

```
#app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    sylius.form.type.channel_pricing.validation_groups: [app_product] # see http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/validation.html
```

---

it result in nothing : in the symfony profiler, the sylius validation group is still appplied.

I can't figured out what I did bad.

please note that :

- I tried to store the parameter into the service.yml file, it did change nothing.
- I don't know how to find the name for the parameter, so I used a name similar to the ressource `sylius.channel_pricing` (see : `bin/console sylius:debug:resource sylius.channel_pricing`)

Comment: I have no idea about Sylius but... What happens if you remove the `NotBlank` rule?

Comment: Hello I just tried, it do change nothing : the validation group remain the one by default `sylius`. It's probably because I choose a bad parameter name, but I can't find out the good one... `sylius.form.type.channel_pricing.validation_groups`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copy paste an answer from @pjedrzejewski :

> Perhaps you should use a promotion to apply proper discount and get
>   the order total to 0? Then Sylius should handle it just fine. I am not
>   sure we should allow setting price 0, it can lead to terrible mistakes

Comment: The default is that I have to activate this promotion in the admin panel in the installation procedure.

Comment: I also had to overwrite many templates in order to replace the non promotional prices with a "free" mention.